# Convert code from Java to PHP format.

Tags: php, arraylist, boolean-expression

I am new to using PHP. I am trying to convert a Java code to PHP but with little success. especially declaring variable type long and also declaring an object of a class as an array.

```
public class Company extends User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8598447488057067508L;

public String id;
public String companyName;
public String companyCode;
public String avatar;

public Price price;
public List<History> history;
public List<Wall> wallpost;

public boolean isFollowing;

public String toString() {
    return "Company [id=" + id 
            + ", companyName=" + companyName 
            + ", companyCode=" + companyCode 
            + ", avatar=" + avatar + "]";
     }
}
```

In PHP

```
 <?php

 include "History.php";
 include "Price.php";
 include "Wall.php";

 class Company extends User implements Serializable {

  private static final  long $serialVersionUID = 8598447488057067508L;// get error here

  public $id;
  public $companyName;
  public $companyCode;
  public $avatar;

  public Price $price;//object of Price Class how to declare this?
  public List<History> $history;//object of History Class how to declare this as a List?
  public List<Wall> $wallpost;//object of Wall Class how to declare this as a list?

  public boolean $isFollowing; //how to assign boolean to this variable?
 }
```

I believe there shud be a way of casting this in PHP.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try any tools to convert java to php?

Comment: @Evan: Can you suggest some free and open source tools?

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed, I tried but had no luck. Check out the result: http://myhashcode.blogspot.sg/2015/02/convert-java-to-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define them as arrays, you can't define a type:

```
<?php

 include "History.php";
 include "Price.php";
 include "Wall.php";

 class Company extends User implements Serializable {

  // Define as constant, include value in quotes
  const serialVersionUID = "8598447488057067508L";

  public $id;
  public $companyName;
  public $companyCode;
  public $avatar;

  public $price;
  public $history = array();
  public $wall = array();

  public $isFollowing;

  public function __construct()
  {
        // Set price
        $price_obj = new Price();
        array_push($this->price, $price_obj);

        // Set history
        $history_obj = new History();
        array_push($this->history, $history_obj);

        // Set wall
        $wall_obj = new Wall();
        array_push($this->wall, $wall_obj);

        // Assign boolean
        $this->isFollowing = true;

  }
 }
```

You can put any type of object in the variables/arrays.

The `final` keyword can only be used on `class`es, but you can define it as a constant.

It's probably a strange concept going from a strongly typed language to a weakly typed one...

Comment: Hi coulton, thanks for your answer but im getting an error with the private const $serialVersionUID = "8598447488057067508L"; "unexpected const","unexpected variable.

Comment: Sorry,  I just noticed the top comment here in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php `It may seem obvious, but class constants are always publicly visible. They cannot be made private or protected. I do not see it state that in the docs anywhere.`.  I have removed the `private` form the constant definition and the `$` for that matter.  Constants don't have a `$`

Comment: Whoops, I missed `function` from the `__construct()` method too.  I've gone all C# on you lol.  I just tested the code and it works correctly now: http://www.tehplayground.com/#kBdKRc9TO